# Meta Box, WordPress and New Tab/Window

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My last question was a bit confusing. So I re-created the question to clarify better. The previous developer of this theme made a lot of options with the function `add_meta_box();` for a slide custom post type.

There are three "meta boxes":

1. Is the "Legenda Banner", to display a text at the slider. It's not used at this website (so Ignore this one);
2. The another one is "Link do Slider", to insert a link at the image. This link can be internal or external.
3. This one a created is the "Target do Banner", to insert a target at the link of the image. If the user choice the option "nova janela" the page will open in a new window (or tab). If the user choice the option "mesma janela", the page will open at the same window (or tab).

The problem is: I can't make the "Target do Banner" works. I did a SELECT. But I don't know what´s the best option.

Also: I know I can make all links open in a external window. But my client is asking for a "choice".

This is the code of the slider.php. Below is the code of index.php (where the slider is generated). The image is a thumbnail.

```
<?php

add_action('init', 'slider_register');

// adiciona ao admin_init a função slider_register. (Toda vez que iniciar o ADMIn iniciara esta função)
// register_post_type(); responsavel para registrar o POST TYPE.

function slider_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Sliders', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Slider', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Adicionar Novo', 'galeria item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Adicionar novo slider'),
    'edit_item' => __('Editar slider'),
    'new_item' => __('Novo slider'),
    'view_item' => __('Ver slider'),
    'search_items' => __('Procurar slider'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nada encontrado'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nada na lixeira'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/slider.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
  );

register_post_type( 'slider' , $args );

}


add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init(){
  add_meta_box("legenda_banner", "Legenda do slider", "legenda_banner", "slider", "side", "low");
  add_meta_box("link_banner", "Link do slider", "link_banner", "slider", "side", "low");
  add_meta_box("target_banner", "Target dp Banner", "target_banner", "slider", "side", "low");
}

function legenda_banner(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $legenda_banner = $custom["legenda_banner"][0];
  ?>
  <label>Legenda do banner:</label>
  <input name="legenda_banner" type="text" value="<?php echo $legenda_banner; ?>" />
  <?php
}

function link_banner(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $link_banner = $custom["link_banner"][0];
  ?>
  <label>Link do banner:</label><br/>
  <input name="link_banner" type="text" value="<?php echo $link_banner; ?>" />

  <?php
}

function target_banner(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $link_banner = $custom["link_banner"][0];
  ?>
  <label>Target do banner:</label><br/>
<select name="target_banner">
  <option value="_blank">Nova Janela</option>
  <option value="_self">Mesma Janela</option>
</select>

  <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "legenda_banner", $_POST["legenda_banner"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "link_banner", $_POST["link_banner"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "target_banner", $_POST["target_banner"]);

}
```

Now the code of index.php (I copied only the code of the slider).

```
                                <section class="banner-main">
                <a href="#" class="prev">Anterior</a><?php
                        $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
                        $args = array(

                            'post_type' => 'slider'
                        );
                        $recentPosts->query($args);
                    ?>

                <ul>


                    <?php 

                          while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post();

                     ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link_banner', true); ?>" target="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'target_banner', true); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></li>

                    <?php endwhile;?>

                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="next">Próximo</a>
            </section>
```

Comment: Many wrong things with your code. For one, updating `$_POST` data without checking for its existence or authenticity (big security hole). [Many working examples](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bsave_post%20%2bupdate_post_meta%20is%3aanswer) in [wordpress.se]. You'd be better off using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and even maintain the same post meta names.

Comment: Hi @brasofilo this code isn't mine. I just "used" the same idea to try to make the page open blank. But I'll use the ADC, thanks.

Comment: If you want to code it yourself, follow WPSE links I've provided. Otherwise, ACF is a great tool. Nowadays, I only do custom fields and meta boxes by hand if the project requires highly customized stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code is a mess, I decided to re-write the code using my style. And I'll also use the [Advanced Custom Field](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin.

Thanks for all the answers.